# How can I get a specific parameter from a Facebook page URL?

Tags: facebook, url, parameters, tabs

Well, I'm trying to get a parameter on my Facebook's Page Tab. (This page tab opens an app I've built). So I'm trying to do something like **"http://www.facebook.com/mypagename/app_156916377306500?tag=iphone"** but nothing happens. Anyone knows how to solve that?

Comment: I already know that Facebook documentations talks about the app_data parameter but its not so clear how can i use it.

Comment: [UPDATED 09-10-2012] I've used the 'app_data' parameter inside a page that it was inside the App, It worked fine! But if I put it on a page inside my fanpage, everytime I access my fanpage and try to get the parameter nothing appears. Can anyone post an example of how to use it inside the fanpage?

Answer (score 0):

It should be clear from the documentation how to use app_data:

`app_data` is the ONLY query string parameter in a page tab app's URL which is passed through to your app, it's present in the `signed_request` which is POSTed to your app's page tab URL, and needs to be decrypted with the app secret (though the SDKs take care of this step for you)

See the [Page Tab App](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) documentation and the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) documentation for more information

Comment: Ok but can you pass a practical example of how we can use it? A little part of code exemplifying my case, how can I get the parameter "tag" above?

Comment: See the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ ) which has an example of parsing it manually, though the PHP SDK automatically does this in Facebook::getSignedRequest()